# Why is LINQ's default ID(Primary Key) ReadOnly=False?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, linq

If I create a table in a MS SQL database with an ID column that is set to Identity, auto increment, and primary key. Why is the associated LINQ object created with the Read Only attribute for this column set to False? This makes it appear that you can insert the ID in LINQ but in practice the value supplied to the ID field is just discarded and the database autonumbers the column. LINQ does not produce an error when trying to insert.

**The ID column in LINQ shows up as:**

Auto Generated Value = True

Primary Key = True

*Read Only = False* (Why? The value cannot be inserted into the database!)

I can understand it the ID value in SQL was set to allow inserts. But in this case the values are just ignored and no error is thrown. Is there a reason that the Read Only value for this type of autogenerated column is not set to True by default?

Thank you!

Comment: Which attribute are you referring to? Read and show the relevant MSDN article. If i look at [`ColumnAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) there's no `ReadOnly` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just because a value is autogenerated, doesn't mean you can't manually insert it. All you need to do is run the following:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table ON
```

Linq has no way to determine you disallowed identity inserts, especially since it's common to turn this on just for a few statements and then turn it back off, so by default it seems to let you. If you, as the programmer, know better, simply turn the flag off.

Comment: I also think that he's referring to a `DataSet` column's attribute `ReadOnly`. Why should it be disallowed to use a property setter on an auto generated column? You could set it to 0, -1, -2 or `int.MinValue` if it's appropriate for your business logic. That the database will generate the new value automatically is not important. A `DataSet` is a memory storage of your data.

Comment: Also, i think that a `DataColumn`'s [`ReadOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx) property is only `true` automatically in one case: a computed column. I have tested it in a `DataSet`. After i've assigned an expression it changed to `ReadOnly=true`.

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for! LINQ cannot detect if inserts are allowed or not in the identity field. Therefore it defaults to allow inserts.  You have also provided a logical reason for this to be the default which is what I was really struggling to graps. Thank you for your help!